# can't test web filtering in M365 dev program

Tags: microsoft365-defender

E5 license has web filtering included but when I go to the Defender mgmt console, I don't see Devices tab. I have 2 devices enrolled and visible in Intune.
Following any guide, including this one I need to go to security.microsoft.com
Navigate to Settings -> Endpoints -> Advanced Feature
https://jeffreyappel.nl/enabling-and-configure-web-content-filtering-in-microsoft-defender-for-endpoint-mde/

I don't see the Devices here. Is that 365 developer license limitation?

Thanks

following
https://jeffreyappel.nl/enabling-and-configure-web-content-filtering-in-microsoft-defender-for-endpoint-mde/

Expecting
security.microsoft.com
Navigate to Settings -> Endpoints -> Advanced Feature

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a limitation of the 365 developer license. I have encountered the same and to resolve this issue the Microsoft Defender for Endpoint Licensing is a requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-endpoint?view=o365-worldwide